# Pick a function by user input

Tags: r, readline

I've a list of functions and I'd like to pick one of them by user input, use it for a regression and then display the output of the function *summary* and *plot*.

```
re_show<-function(y){
        f1<-x+I(x^2)
        f2<-I(x^0.5)+I(x^2)
        ...
        f20<-x+I(x^0.5)+I(x^2)

        message("Choose the model")
        i <- readLines(n = 1)
        summary(lm(y~i))
        plot(lm(y~i))
        }
```

Have you got any ideas about how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Try creating the formula as a chracter string first, and then convert to formula (assuming the user input defines the right-hand side of the model equation): `formula(paste("y~",i,sep=""))`

Comment: @Ndr, do you want the user to specify the f function (e.g. f1, f2, etc.) or the variable?  If the former, `switch` is a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is the most generalized answer I can provide for your function.  I have altered it to accept a dependent variable, an independent variable, and a dataset.  If you do not like this option, you can always set the parameters to a default value or modify the function to your particular scenario.  This function, as it stands, will allow you to use any dataset you wish (given no provided sample data).  I have also added a `switch` statement to allow the user to choose which model to use from stdin.  A simple example is shown with the `iris` dataset.

```
re_show<-function(dv, iv, dat){

  # Define your variables to evaluate
  x <- dat[,iv]
  y <- dat[,dv]

  # choose the function
  message("Choose the model")
  fun <- readLines(n = 1)

  # The switch statement
  i <- switch(fun, 
                f1 = {x+I(x^2)},
                f2 = {I(x^0.5)+I(x^2)},
                # add your remaining functions
                f20 = {x+I(x^0.5)+I(x^2)}
  )

  # finish your analysis
  print(summary(lm(y~i)))
  plot(lm(y~i))
}

data(iris)
re_show("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", iris)
```